# laravel orm : where condition on table -> related table -> related table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

so here is my database for a book store

```
books : id ,title 
category : id,  title 

book_category : id , book_id,  category_id 
book_stock : id , book_id , quantity , price
```

considering all the relations are defined in the model , i can query `book_stock` it goes something like this

```
Stock::with('Book')->get();
```

but what if i want to get `stock` of a `book` in the `category = 1`

i can use use condition on book

```
Stock::with('Book' , function($q){
   $q->where(['title'=>'abc']);
})->get();
```

but how can i filter related table of book ? 
basically i want to get `book_id` from `book_category` where `category_id = 1` and then use those ids to filter my `books` finally get `stock`

> ps : i don't want to use query builder

Comment: `...with('Book.stock', function($q){...}`

Comment: @Andrew  i dont see any reference to `book_category` in there ?

Comment: Add it as needed, you can do all the `with`'s you want. `with('Book.stock', 'Book.category')`.

Comment: Yep, should work fine. Technically speaking.

Comment: @Andrew thanx , post it as answer so i could  select it as the right answer

Comment: Does it work fine? I don't wanna post it as an answer unless all your requirements are met.

Comment: @Andrew well i didnt get any error ... but i havn't seeded my database yet so i'm not sure if it'll return expected result  , i'll get back to you after seeding

Comment: Please do, if it doesn't work properly, we'll take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
Stock::with('Book.stock', 'Book.category')->get();
```

You can access any number of nested relations within a `with` statement.

---

Related question:

[Laravel nested relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628754/laravel-nested-relationships)

---

Armin Sam's answer should also be a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

This will return you all books belonging to category=1 with their stock information:

```
$categoryId = 1;

$books = Book::with('stock')->whereHas('category', function($query) use ($categoryId) {
    return $query->where('id', $categoryId);
})->get();
```