# Accessing more remote model in Laravel 5.4 -updated

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three models

```
Photo  
 -id  
 -path_full  
Person  
-id  
-name  
Face  
-id  
-person_id //was people_id  
-photo_id
```

I am trying to access the person name from the Photo model.
Face Model:

```
public function photo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Photo::class);
}

public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class);
}
```

Photo Model:

```
public function faces()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Face::class);
}
```

Person Model:

```
public function faces()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Face::class);
}
```

In my controller I load the Photos like this:

```
$photos = Photo::with('faces')->paginate();
```

In my blade template I want to access the name of the face in the photo.
I got this far.
This is in a foreach hence singular $photo:

```
{{implode($photo->faces->pluck('people_id')->toArray(),', ')}}
```

How can I get the name of the person instead?

**Solution**
I needed this in my view and note my change to the db to person_id so eloquent could do it's magic.

```
//Controller:
$photos = Photo::with('faces.person')->paginate();

//View:
@foreach($photo->faces as $face)
      {{$face->person['name']}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Isn't this a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: A face is a unique face in a specific photo so it always belongs to a single photo. This from facial recognition. A person can have many faces in many photos. A face can only belong to one person.

Comment: so, are you trying to get a photo and then the person's name of each face?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 2):

You can eager load the `person` data **all the time** you call `faces` on the Photo's model:

```
// Photo.php
public function faces()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Face::class)->with('person');
}
```

Or in your query, you can do this to eager load **only at that time**:

```
$photos = Photo::with('faces', 'faces.person')->paginate();
```

Now you can access like this:

```
$photos->first()->faces->first()->person->name; // will print the name of the person of the first face of the first photo...
```

I hope this answer can be helpful.

Comment: when i dd($photo->face) I get this: Collection {#355 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Face {#376 ▼
      #table: "faces"
      #attributes: array:13 [▼
        "id" => 181
        "photo_id" => 16
        "people_id" => 1
       
      ]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "person" => null
      ]
      
    }
  ]
} Notice Person is Null.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My issue was people_id should be person_id. Laravel takes the model name not the table name

Comment: Great @BobB, I think would be helpful if you update your question.

Comment: Still having this fail dd($photo->faces->person); Am I missing something as dd($photo->faces); has the correct data for person

Comment: Pastebin it your `dd($photo->faces);`

Comment: This is strange, it seems it could be accessible through `$photo->faces->person`

Comment: Agreed. Property [person] does not exist on this collection instance. Strange.

Comment: @BobB We are tying to get `persons` on a Collection, do this: `$photo->faces->first()->person`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152783/discussion-between-ian-rodrigues-and-bobb).

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the person of the face by changing your query like so:

```
Photo::with(['faces' => function($query) {$query->with('person')}])->paginate();
```

I am not quite sure about the syntax, but this is how you can nest relations in an eloquent model. A shorter way to write this might be: `Photo::with('faces.person')->paginate();`

Some more information is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628754/laravel-nested-relationships).