# double link laravel tables

Tags: laravel, vue.js, controller

I'm creating an e-commerce in laravel and vue js. I am in the following situation

```
    public function show(Product $product){
    return $product -> load('categories' , 'images', 'reviews');
}
```

From this through an axios I can trace all my tables connected to the products. Now, however, I would need to trace from reviews also the users table with which they have a connection. How can I do this on my controller?
Such a thing

```
return $ product -> load ('categories', 'images', 'reviews' -> with ('user');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have relations in `reviews` for `user`, you can do this.

```
return $product->load('categories' , 'images', 'reviews', 'reviews.user');
```

Some helpful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628754/laravel-nested-relationships).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function show(Product $product)
{
    return $product->load('categories', 'images', 'reviews.user');
}
```

Or some advance level if you want to perform where query or access query builder

```php
public function show(Product $product)
{
    return $product->load([
        'categories',
        'images',
        'reviews' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('field', 'value')->with('user');
        },
    ]);
}
```