# Laravel - How to pluck objects in nested relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tables

```
persons:
id = 1
name = 'john'

class_of_pesson:
id = 1,
desc = 'employee'

classes_of_person:
persons_id = 1
class_of_pesson_id = 1

Persons::with('classes_of_person.class_of_pesson')->paginate(10);
```

data:

```
[
{ id: 1, name: 'jonh', classes_of_person: [ {person_id: 1, class_id: 1, class_of_pesson: { id: 1, desc: 'employee' } } ] }
]
```

wanted:

```
[
{ id: 1, name: 'jonh', classes_of_person: [{id: 1, desc: 'employee'}] }
]
```

I tried the pluck method but I am confused. Can anyone help me with this?

Edit:

Models Relationship

```
Persons
public function classes_of_person() {
    return $this->hasMany(classes_of_person::class, 'person_id', 'id');
}

ClassesOfPersons
public function classe_of_person() {
    return $this->hasOne(classe_of_pesson::class, 'id', 'class_of_person_id')
}
```

Solved with belongsToMany in person model. Thanks for all

```
Ex: function classes_of_person () {
   return $this->belongsToMany(classe_of_pesson::class);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628754/laravel-nested-relationships

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to define a **HasManyThrough** relation in your model then use it in your query with the "**with**" function.

Check the reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: could you show me an example using my models please?

Comment: Solved with belongsToMany in person model
https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/