# Laravel possible way to write raw SQL query as Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I've got problem with selection from my database.

This is how my query should look like:

```
  SELECT `deads`.`id`, `graves`.*, `places`.`row`, `places`.`place`, `places`.`id_quarter`, `places`.`occupied` FROM `deads` LEFT JOIN `graves` ON `deads`.`id_grave` = `graves`.`id` LEFT JOIN `places` ON `graves`.`id_place` = `places`.`id` WHERE `places`.`id_quarter` = '1' AND `places`.`occupied` = '1'
```

My Dead model:

```
 public function graves()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Grave::class,'id_grave');
        }
```

My Grave model:

```
public function places()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Place::class,'id_place');
}

public function deads()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Dead::class);
}
```

My Place model:

```
public function quarters()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Quarter::class,'id_quarter');
    }

    public function graves()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Grave::class,'id_grave');
    }
```

I can't get the idea, how I can write this as eloquent select. I want to bypass future injection problems. Is there any way to get it smoothly or should I leave it as RAW SQL query? How to convert it to an array like I get it when I use eloquent?

Comment: how about Dead::with(['gaves.places'])->get(); if you want to filter the relation you can use whereHas etc.

Comment: Here is the link to docs for relations querying https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: I want to select all deads, which grave is in quarter = 1.

Comment: Dead::with(['graves.places'])->get() returns all data from these relations, how I can add to where that clause?

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36498701/5676711

Comment: Something like this will be valid? 
$deads = Dead::with(['graves.places' => function($query){
            $query->select('id_quarter')->where('id_quarter','=',1);
        }])->get();
But how to write variable instead int value in this select? It says that variable is undefined.

Comment: $deads = Dead::with(['graves.places' => function($query) use($variable){ $query->select('id_quarter')->where('id_quarter', '=', $variable); }])->get();

Comment: This query don't filter if it's in specific quarter :(

Comment: It returns all items from Dead.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? Return all deads from with graves which are located in a quarter? and can you share the DB table structure as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225862/discussion-between-hamid-ali-and-wpcpremium80).