# How to get last relation in a nested relationship in Laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

`ServiceCategory` has many `Service`

```
public function services(): HasMany {
    return $this->hasMany(Service::class, 'category_id');
}
```

`Service` has many `Price`

```
public function prices(): HasMany {
    return $this->hasMany(ServicePrice::class, 'service_id');
}
```

Let's say `prices` table has a `price_value` column, how do I get the lowest and highest price?

I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25628830) but every time the query returns a list of `ServiceCategory` instead of a list of `Price`.

What I tried:

```
ServiceCategory::with('services.prices')->get();
// Or Even
ServiceCategory::first()->with('services.prices')->get();
```

And:

```
ServiceCategory::has('services')->with('services:category_id')->with(['services.prices' => function ($q) {
    $q->select('price');
}])->get();
```

Still no chance to only return a collection of `Price`

Answer (score 0):

Finally after trying every method that eloquent lets me to try I found this solution (I should have thought from the other side):

```
$category = ServiceCategory::firstOrFail();

$minPrice = ServicePrice::whereHas('service', function ($q) use ($category) {
    $q->whereCategoryId($category->id);
})->select('price')->min('price'); 

// Instead of min() you can use get() to list all prices.
```

But please let me know if this method is not optimal in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an [Has One Of Many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many).
You can define the highest and lowest price on the Service:

```php
/**
 * Get the service's highest price.
 */
public function highestPrice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ServicePrice::class)->ofMany('price_value', 'max');
}

/**
 * Get the service's lowest price.
 */
public function lowestPrice()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ServicePrice::class)->ofMany('price_value', 'min');
}
```

Not sure why you would want a Collection of all the lowest and highest prices but you could use those relations and some [Collection functions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#available-methods) to create a collection of only the prices

```php
Services::with(['highestPrice', 'lowestPrice'])
    ->map(function(Service $service) {
        return [$service->highestPrice, $service->lowestPrice];
    })
    ->flatten();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I don't want a collection of lowest or highest, I just want the lowest and the highest price related to a specific category.

Comment: I see the Price also has a category_id, then define the Has One Of Many relationship on the ServiceCategory.

Comment: No, ```Price``` only has a single foreign key which is ```service_id```.