# Laravel Eloquent join multiple nested tables with condition on the last table, custom column select

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Lets say I have models A, B ,C and D as well as A_TYPE which is a data type table for A)
I know that in D, there is a column `another_system_id` (which is what I have.

I want to retrieve all model A entities, which tie into it, while also selecting columns from A, A_TYPE and D (`foreign_system_id, another_entity_id`)

The relevant relationships:

Model A

```
public function bs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(B::class);
}
```

And also

```
public function b_type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(BType::class);
}
```

Model B:

```
public function cs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(C::class);
}
```

Next one is a bit trickier, there is no formal FK relationship in the DB between C and D for reasons outside the scope of the question, so I added this:

Model C

```
public function system_source()
{
    return $this->hasOne(D::class, 'id', 'datasource_object_id');
}
```

Then, based on similar question at [Laravel nested relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628754/laravel-nested-relationships), when I try to do:

```
$a = A::with('B.C.system_source')
    ->whereHas('B.C.d_source', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->whereIn('another_system_id', array(9575, 9576));
    });
```

When dumping the `toSql` output of this, it looks like so:

```
select * 
from `as` 
where exists (
    select * 
    from `bs` 
    where `as`.`id` = `bs`.`b_id` 
    and exists (select * 
        from `cs` 
        where `bs`.`id` = `cs`.`c_id` 
        and exists (select * 
            from `ds` 
            where `cs`.`datasource_object_id` = `ds`.`id` 
            and `another_system_id` in (?, ?))));
```

When I substitute the two question marks, I get a single result.
However when I try to let Laravel run it using `get()->count()`, I get 0!

I am at a loss, here is the simple query in human written SQL syntax to get the correct results:

```
        SELECT d.form_id, d.question_id, a.id, a.`name`, a.parent_id, at.`name` as 'A Type'
        FROM a
        JOIN a_types at ON a.a_type_id = at.id
        JOIN b on b.a_id = a.id
        JOIN c on c.b_id = b.id
        JOIN d on d.id = c.datasource_object_id
        WHERE d.another_system_id in (9576, 9575);
```

You can see my problem, two issues:

1. How do I select the columns? I have tried so many different ways like suggested in the link using `::with` with function for each nested level.
2. The generated query is MUCH worse in performance, about twice worse compared to hand written one! I would like Eloquent to generate query like the one I wrote, which is simple and efficient

Comment: try using only `count()` instead of doing `get()->count()`

Comment: for selecting you can use ->select() method, even inside with(). You can also use withWhereHas (from L9.something)

Comment: Thanks guys, but all of that still doesn't generate the effective query with JOINs, instead it is using a nested WHERE EXISTS hierarchy which I don't think is as efficient?